# How I can install PyQt5 on ubuntu 20.04 for python 2

Tags: python, pyqt5

How I can install PyQt5 on ubuntu 20.04 for python 2. I tried with pip command and doesn't work.

I need to install for pycontact software.

Comment: Are you sure you want to install it for Python 2? The `setup.py` of pycontact claims it requires 3.6.

Comment: "pip install pycontact"
**Please make sure that pip installs PyContact for Python version 2.7, not 3 or higher**.
I take this from the tutorial of pycontact.
My problem is how I can install pycontact with python 2 and pyqt5 can be installed  Only with Python v3.5 or later

Comment: The author seems to have [changed his mind](https://github.com/maxscheurer/pycontact/commit/89a2fab8382228e6a352683f5e914e2f4b32dc7f) within 42min after the release…and never published that. Also try not to base any work on project that are not properly maintained.

Comment: The current [README](https://github.com/maxscheurer/pycontact#readme) states: "PyContact requires at least **Python 3.6** installed on your system".

Answer (score 0):

Not possible.

From the [documentation](https://doc.bccnsoft.com/docs/PyQt5/installation.html):

> Only Python v3.5 and later is supported.